# Live Video Encoding Using Intel Quick Sync and Opencv Is Slow

Tags: opencv, intel, h.264, video-encoding, yuv

I want to develop one software that takes frames from 4K camera and encodes it simultaneously.
And right-now I can get the frames and compress it to a .h264 file. However, The problem is, I want to get 10 FPS from my video.(I mean the video eventually becomes 10FPS, but while encoding process, it doesn't get all the frames.(I am getting in between 3-5 FPS).When I dig the code I have realized that, the encoding function is okay but the function that converts BGR->YUV is pretty slow. Also, in my case, there is one dedicated computer and camera for this software. That computer only has intel integrated GPU.(so, Using FFMPEG with NVIDIA GPU is not possible.)
How could I make this faster?
This is the code I am using:
` int main()
{

```
Mat frame;
VideoCapture vcap(0);
vcap.set(3, 3840);
vcap.set(4, 2160);

if (!vcap.isOpened()) {
    std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}


int frame_width = vcap.get(3);
int frame_height = vcap.get(4);
VideoWriter video;
std::cout << video.open("out.h264", CAP_INTEL_MFX, VideoWriter::fourcc('H', '2', '6', '4'), 10, Size(frame_width, frame_height), true);
for (;;) {

    vcap >> frame;
    video.write(frame);
}


return  -1;
```

}`

The conversion function BGR->YUV takes about 0.20 seconds(~5 FPS).
The encoding function takes about 0.045(~20FPS) seconds.

I was thinking the encoding would take time, but apparently conversion part takes a lot more, which is odd. There must be a solution for this.

GPU: Intel(R) UDH Graphics 620

CPU: Intel Core i5-8350U 1.70GHZ(8 Core)

Okay, so this is the write_one() function from OpenCV, it converts the frame to YUV and encodes it.This function is callled in every frame. The function named cvtBGRtoTwoPlaneYUV() does the conversion from BGR->YUV.(TAKES 200 MS )

```
    bool VideoWriter_IntelMFX::write_one(cv::InputArray bgr)
{
   
 mfxStatus res;
    mfxFrameSurface1 *workSurface = 0;
    mfxSyncPoint sync;
    clock_t start1 = clock();
    if (!bgr.empty() && (bgr.dims() != 2 || bgr.type() != CV_8UC3 || bgr.size() != frameSize))
    {
        MSG(cerr << "MFX: invalid frame passed to encoder: "
            << "dims/depth/cn=" << bgr.dims() << "/" << bgr.depth() << "/" << bgr.channels()
            << ", size=" << bgr.size() << endl);
        return false;

    }

    if (!bgr.empty())
    {
        workSurface = pool->getFreeSurface();
        if (!workSurface)
        {
            // not enough surfaces
            MSG(cerr << "MFX: Failed to get free surface" << endl);
            return false;
        }
        Mat src = bgr.getMat();
        hal::cvtBGRtoTwoPlaneYUV(src.data, src.step,
                                 workSurface->Data.Y, workSurface->Data.UV, workSurface->Data.Pitch,
                                 workSurface->Info.CropW, workSurface->Info.CropH,
                                 3, false, 1);
    }
    clock_t end1 = clock();
   
    clock_t start = clock();
    while (true)
    {
     
        outSurface = 0;
        DBG(cout << "Calling with surface: " << workSurface << endl);
        res = encoder->EncodeFrameAsync(NULL, workSurface, &bs->stream, &sync);
        if (res == MFX_ERR_NONE)
        {
            res = session->SyncOperation(sync, getWriterTimeoutMS()); // TODO: provide interface to modify timeout
            if (res == MFX_ERR_NONE)
            {
                // ready to write
                if (!bs->write())
                {
                    MSG(cerr << "MFX: Failed to write bitstream" << endl);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    DBG(cout << "Write bitstream" << endl);
                    /*RSI*/
                    clock_t end = clock();
                    frame_info[0] += (double(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
                    frame_info[2] += (double(end1 - start1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
                    frame_info[1]++;
                    /*RSI*/
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MSG(cerr << "MFX: Sync error: " << res << endl);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (res == MFX_ERR_MORE_DATA)
        {
            DBG(cout << "ERR_MORE_DATA" << endl);
            return false;
        }
        else if (res == MFX_WRN_DEVICE_BUSY)
        {
            DBG(cout << "Waiting for device" << endl);
            sleep_ms(1000);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            MSG(cerr << "MFX: Bad status: " << res << endl);
            return false;
        }
      
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Since you are a new contributor: You provided very information about the hardware that you are using.
At a minimum we would need CPU generation type of integrated graphics, Intel driver version etc.
Moving forward you will get more attention if you provide more details.
Right now all I could do is guess.
So please expand on the hardware information.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have added my gpu & cpu specs. But this problem have to be solved without playing with any hardware.

Comment: you should interface with ffmpeg directly. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for transcoding video.

Comment: I must use hardware encoding. Ffmpeg only works with software encoding with my computer. And it is slow. Also opencv has features with Intel quick sync. why it is just for computer vision?

Comment: I think you should use whatever tool you are comfortable with.
FFMPEG supports Quick Sync:


https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync

Comment: It would not matter, because as long as we are using Intel quick Sync, I have to pass YUV frames and I would need to convert BGR Frames to YUV.

Comment: I am pretty sure Quick Sync has a RGB -> YUV pixel format converter.
It is probably BGRA ->NV12. In an ideal world your bitmap is uploaded to GPU memory, converted to NV12 and then encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is facing with the same issue. After deeper search I have found that intel also has a function does BGR->YUV conversion using hardware acceleration. It is fast comparing the above cvtBGRtoTwoPlaneYUV() function(~4x times faster). However, it was still slow for my use case. I had to get 30FPS using Intel(R) UDH Graphics 620, apparently the only solution for now is getting a better GPU.
The samples for use case:
https://github.com/sivabudh/intel-media-sdk-tutorials/tree/master/simple_6_encode_vmem_vpp_preproc

I just have added OpenCV X86 lib and I have written my own function that reads from CV::MAT  rather than a file.

Comment: My i7-6700k desktop (HD 630 graphics, aka Gen 9) can transcode 3840x2160p h.264 at 61 fps.  `ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv  -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_qsv -global_quality 25 -look_ahead 1 -an output.mkv` with FFmpeg n4.4.1.  `intel_gpu_top` shows the "video" block at 97 to 98% utilization while this is running.  (Linux 5.16,  `energy_performance_preference` set to `performance`, using dual-channel DDR4-2666 RAM.  The input file was low bitrate for that resolution, 9.1 mbps, and no colour-space conversion was needed, just yuv420p.  But software decode of h.264 isn't trivial!)

Comment: Anyway, I'd guess that your laptop CPU probably has the same fixed-function video encode/decode block as mine.  Unless FFmpeg is using faster / lower-quality-per-bitrate settings than the functions you're calling, your GPU should be capable, if software is optimized sufficiently to pipeline the work.  Unless maybe you're encoding yuv444p h.264, instead of the usual 4:2:0 sub-sampling (1/4 the chroma resolution)?

Comment: GPU hardware video scaling / colour-space conversion should be possible using shaders like `mpv` does, or in software.  Or just using a bit of time and reducing encode FPS a bit below that 61 fps best(?) case.  BTW, https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync has sample FFmpeg commands.  And the output bitrate from my encode was 21 mbps for some random live-action 30fps content, 46 mbps for another with sharper details in the source (48 fps to transcode from wmv; ffmpeg's WMV decoder is less efficient, and the "video" block wasn't maxed out in `intel_gpu_top`)

Comment: Thank you for the comments, i have checked multiple times, the samplings, resolutions, codecs are correct. I also got similar FPS when i tried with a VIDEO file. The problem occurs when I try to do it with live video.(Capturing frames from Opencv). The problem might possibly because of  pipeline. But i am still pretty sure that i am doing right, because i have put the clock inside the code, and realized that conversion takes time rather than encoding.(i could JUST encode 50 FPS).

Comment: I didn't think conversion would be that expensive if done with AVX2 SIMD, or GPU hardware.  What speed of RAM do you have?  Mine is dual-channel DDR4-2666, and `intel_gpu_top` showed something like 17500 MB/s read + 7400 MB/s write while transcoding at 62 fps.  So FFmpeg decode + encode is pretty bandwidth-intensive.  But copying 24bpp RGB (not sub-sampled) at 30fps is only 746.496 MB/s, so even if it takes multiple copies of the data, I wouldn't expect that to eat so much bandwidth that it steals too much bandwidth from encode.  IDK, maybe getting data from the camera is a problem?

Comment: My RAM also has similar specs, and I have tried the camera, I was getting 30FPS without any issue using OpenCV. Also the thing that confuses me is, why OpenCV did not implement Intel quickSync using video preprocessing(the  intel function that uses hardware acceleration for conversion).And wrote own conversion function which is extremely slow.